# Change the size of android Checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my Android application I need to change the size of the android checkbox. I searched and understood it can not be done by simply changing the properties. I found the [THIS LINK](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html) but can't really figure out what exactly have to do. [Can't find this link, "android-sdk-windows-1.0_r2\tools\lib\res\default\values\themes.xml"].

Can Someone please help me to achieve this??? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path for themes.xml and styles.xml is changed from the given one to `android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\values` (android-8 is for API-level 8). 
The drawable btn_check.xml is available at `android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable`, while the other drawable components are available at respective hdpi / mdpi folders.

2) You simply need to include the respective drawables of the checkbox in different states (i.e. focused, pressed, checked, or normal), and a drawable for the background as well (often the nine-patch file given in the link). 
Include these in the respective xml to specify the looks of the checkbox as given in the link, and include that xml in the `android:button` and `android:background` attributes of your checkbox. That should do it all...! :)