# CheckBox ReSize

Tags: android, xamarin.android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the size of android Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242163/change-the-size-of-android-checkbox)

Another thing Android has made harder than it needs to be.  I found [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html) but not only can I not follow where exactly existing android code ends and where I'm supposed to begin coding/editing/adding, but I don't seem to have the file path he's included.

```
android-sdk-windows-1.0_r2\tools\lib\res\default\values\themes.xml
```

I have

```
android-sdk\tools\lib
```

but then that is where the similarities end.  I do not have a res folder in there.  Can someone provide an example or a resource that gives a clear way to just make a CheckBox larger?

Comment: You have a newer SDK package, it should be located somewhere like this - android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11\data\res\values\themes.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the related Drawable and set them in the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new checkbox" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_checkbox_background"
    android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
```

Comment: link is broken.  I've tried creating a shape in drawable set to my desirned background color and shape size and setting that as the background to my checkbox, but then the checkbox stops showing up at all.  Don't really know what you are referencing for android:button.  What is the my_checkbox drawable representing? A selector resource, and image?